# How to keep only certain words in the string using C#?

Tags: c#, string

Couldn't really find a question like that, closest I could find was how to keep only numeric characters or only letters in the string. Googled a lot, but don't have an idea where to even start.

For example, we have a input string `"OAK PRO DASH CAN USA DASH BEN"`.
We have particular words, for example - `"DASH "`, `"USA "`, `"BRO "`, so we need to "scan" the string and keep only them there, hence skipping or "removing" all parts of the string which are not in that list. So that we should have an output string like `"DASH USA DASH "` in that case.

Thank you!

P.S. Wanted to add a detail - *the keywords can also consist of several words in a row and have spaces*, so its more like sets of characters than words. For example `"OAK PRO"`, so splitting everything in input over the space character can mess with that logic, unfortunately.

Comment: [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) the string over  the space character, loop over the resulting array, and add the words you want to keep to a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Why do you think “OAK PRO” is one keyword instead of two? Why isn't “OAK PRO DASH” one keyword?

Comment: because its more like a set of strings which should be used in filtering, it can also be "OAK PRO DASH" as well, I've used "OAK PRO" for the sake of showing that there can be spaces in those keywords.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily obtain your result using Linq.

```
string source = "OAK PRO DASH CAN USA DASH BEN";
List<string> keywords = new List<string> { "DASH", "USA", "BRO"};  

var x = source.Split(' ');
var result = string.Join(" ", x.Where(p => keywords.Contains(p)));
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Notice that I have removed the unnecessary space that you have after the key words that you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you! I've added a comment to a question, unfortunately those keywords can have several words in them, quite an important detail I've forgot to tell about right away. So splitting over spaces logic wouldn't work with that as it seems.